# sql command for modify a column to have 2 digits after decimal point

Tags: sql

What is the sql command for modify a column to have 2 digits after decimal point?
Not just casting it when display.

Comment: the datatype for this column was number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a `DECIMAL` data type.  Each database has its own documentation for this.

The declaration is something like `DECIMAL(8, 2)`, for instance.  You need to specify both the scale and the precision.

Comment: In your example, is "8" just the length before decimal point or is it the total length of the number, including 2 digits after the point?

Comment: @tic30 . . . 8 is called the scale of the number.  It means that the number consists of 8 digits, 2 after the decimal place and 6 before.